# Configure usjon to return datetime as datetime objects rather than int utc timestamp

Tags: python, json, datetime

[ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) dumps python datetime objects as UTC timestamp (int value). Is it possible to configure a custom encoder for ujson to dump datetime as sting in isoformat?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) does not allow this. `ujson` only accepts 3 encoding options: `encode_html_chars`, `ensure_ascii` and `double_precision`.

Could use other lib, e.g. [simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson), but looks like `ujson` is the fastest.

The solution: convert python datetime objects to ISO formatted string before the json serialization.

Comment: Yeah its really a shame you can't pass a custom JSONEncoder to ujson.dumps

Answer (score 1):

To extend Daria's solution of converting datetime objects into ISO formatted strings before the json serialization, you could write a wrapper that takes care of converting the dates back into datetime objects when you load the json data.